# Sorting a map with a key and a pair as the value?

Tags: c++, maps

I am trying to sort a map that has a Key as the String, and a pair having unsigned long long, when i use the sort() method from #include  i am trying to over load the < operator but when i pass the address of the beginning of the map and the end i cannot access map.first, map.second.first, or map.second.second

does anyone have any ideas

```
map<string, pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>> ext_count;
    sort(map.rbegin(), map.rend()); // to sort descending
bool operator < (map<string, pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>>& lhs, map<string, pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long>>& rhs) {
return lhs.first < rhs.first;
```

}

Comment: Um, a map is a sorted container.  You cannot sort a map

Comment: Map is ordered container, which can not be `sorted` - you can only define one sort order, which will always be used for this map.

Comment: So how would i change the sort order?

Comment: The only way I can see is to copy the map into another map with a different sort order.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, one way is to copy the map to a map with a different sort order.

Here is a small example of accomplishing this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// define the Sorter template class.  If sortdir == true, then we sort ascending
template <bool sortdir = true>
struct Sorter
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& left, const std::string& right)
    {
        if ( sortdir )
            return left < right;
        return left > right;
    }
};

// our test maps
typedef std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> mapDataType;

// ascending map
std::map<std::string, mapDataType, Sorter<>> myMap = 
                            {{"abc", {0,0}}, {"def",{0,1}}};

// descending map
std::map<std::string, mapDataType, Sorter<false>> myMap2; // descending map

// sample program
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // copy ascending map to descending map
    std::copy(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), 
              std::inserter(myMap2, myMap2.begin()));
}
```

Note that we used the third parameter in the `std::map` declaration to specify the sorter predicate.

In addition, the `std::copy` function is used to simply copy all elements from source map to destination map.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/LEHOzd)